# Find Client IPs with their username

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11gR, there are multiple users, But we don't know their client IP, We want to know client IPs with their username.

Regards,
Taoqir

Comment: Thanks Taoqir.  A given user can establish different connections at different times from different IP addresses.  Are you looking for the IP for a session?

Comment: One other question -- have you tried `UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS`?  This function has ACL security to setup but can return IP given a host (V$SESSION).

Comment: Thanks Alexgibbs. You are right, a user can establish different connections from different IP addresses, I can want to capture all address, actually there are multiple users I don't know their purpose, by doing this i can find the user's purpose either is an application user or db link user.

Comment: Thanks Taoqir, that is interesting.  If your goal is to differentiate types of users, `V$SESSION` may have all that is needed -- it includes osuser name, client machine name, service, program, module, etc. etc.  If you still need IP, UTL_INADDR should let you convert machine to IP.

Comment: Thanks Alexgibbs, My database version Oracle 11gR2 (11.2.0.3), and this query is not working,   ' SELECT username, status, osuser, process, machine, terminal, logon_time,
    lockwait, blocking_session_status, blocking_instance, blocking_session,
    UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS(REGEXP_REPLACE(machine, '^.+\\')) AS client_ip  
FROM v$session;'